# Check if one propType is used with another inside Component

Tags: reactjs, properties, components

Still rather new-ish to React here, but I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a **component is using a certain prop in conjunction with another**? For example:

`<Graph x={[1, 2, 3, 4]} points={10} />`

Let's assume the points prop assigns a random 10 points to the Graph component, but someone using the component can also pass in an `x` prop with an array of number values.

Theoretically, I'd like to implement a feature in which using the `points` prop when the `x` prop is already in use would throw an error in React or warn the user somehow. Perhaps at this point with something as simple as a `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that using propTypes

```
propTypes: {
  points: function(props, propName, componentName) {
     if(props.x != undefined){
        console.log("You cannot use points and x at the same time");
        return new Error("You cannot use points and x at the same time"); // Use this if you want to throw an error.
     }
  }
}
```

Here is an example -> https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41180/